# Can't find which file sends the contact form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, modx, ajaxform

ModX website has a working contact form with the following structure:

```
                    <form id="hi" action="#">
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="hisend">

                              ... just some plain input fields ...

                            <input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

When user submits the form, the following jQuery code handles it:

```
$("#hi").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var r = new Date().getTime();
    $.post('/ajax.html?ts'+r, $("#hi").serialize(), function(data){
        if(data == 'OK'){
             // ... just some simple thank you message ...
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

QUESTION: I need to change an address to which this form sends emails, but can't figure where it is/how this form works?

Logically, I'd look into `ajax.html` for further clues, but I can't see the file, neither from ModX manager, neither from web host provided File Manager (I don't have FTP access.)

The file seems to be there though, and gives response 200 when accessed directly from the browser, but no output.

Any hint much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked .htaccess to see if there are any redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the file might be index-ajax.php. I suspect there might be a .htaccess redirect for ajax.html to index-ajax.php

Comment: Looked into .htaccess, but not 100% sure if there's a redirect - however, there is indeed index-ajax.php, which also doesn't seem to send any emails, so now I'm looking through the files it includes.

Comment: Sounds like the way to go! If it helps you, please accept my answer.

Comment: Ok, I sifted through all the files included by index-ajax.php and there's nothing giving even a hint of sending email. Not sure what to try next.

Comment: Why not grep through the code with the email address you would like to change and if that is not specific, the exact text in the message and start from there?

Comment: Due to limited access, this also helped me grep using php: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/29914/65847